# How to compare two array lists that consist of instances of objects that belong to the same superclass, but various subclasses.

Tags: java, oop, object, if-statement, arraylist

So far I came up with that.

```
public static boolean challenge(ArrayList<Thing> required, ArrayList<Thing> owned){

    boolean result=false;

    for(int i=0; i<=required.size(); i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<=owned.size(); j++)
        {
            ///compare each required to all owned
            ///if (required.get(i) instanceof owned.get(j))
            {   result=true;
            }

            /// else
            {
                result=false;
                break;
            }
        }   
    }

    return result;
}
```

it gives me compile error in the if statement. 
" ')' expected "

I am a bit lost. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The problem is not clear from your explanation. If you just want to find the difference between required and owned, take a look at CollectionUtils.retainAll function, it is more efficient than M*N operation in two nested loops.

And if you are just confused about the instanceof operator in the code, the immediate problem is that it does not work with two class instances, the right part should be type, not object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alex Nevidomsky said, `instanceof` should be used with the type  on the right part.  Should be `if (required.get(i) instanceof owned.get(j).getClass())` [maybe this link will be helpful also](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=31)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use `required.get(i).getClass() == owned.get(j).getClass()` instead.

Also consider using 'for each' e.g.

```
for(Thing r : required) {
    for (Thing o : owned) {
      if (r.getClass() ...
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that foreach advice looks really important to me, because the first thing I noticed was the off-by-one error that will most definitely result in ArrayOutOfBounds exception. I'd recommend you mentioning this in the answer more clearly.

Comment: @SCYV @cdshines BTW using `==` for comparing classes can be misleading. First of all, each class is an object per se, so comparing with `==` you compare references to classes as objects, not objects. That means if you compare subclass on the left side and its parent class on the right side using `==`, you get false. Using `instanceof` instead of `==` on the same place will return true. Please refer to [link](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0060__Operators/TheinstanceofKeyword.htm)